# Add a unique id for a couple of columns in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers

First of all, this problem comes from my company's database and I can't change anything about the structure of this table because it can impact other projects.

I have a table T_CONTACT with 5 columns : CTO_RECNUM, CTO_COMPANY, CTO_NAME, CTO_TYPE, CTO_INFO.

Each row in this table represent one information about a contact.

For example, in the table we have:

```
CTO_RECNUM  CTO_COMPANY     CTO_NAME    CTO_TYPE    CTO_INFO
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
12435       HIS COMPANY     Mr. SCOTT   'TEL'       'phone_number_here'
12436       HIS COMPANY     Mr. SCOTT   'FAX'       'fax_number_here'
12437       HIS COMPANY     Mr. SCOTT   'EML'       'email_adresse_here'
12438       OTHER COMPANY   Mr. PAUL    'FAX'       'fax_number_here'
```

I want to add a new column to have a unique id for the two columns (CTO_COMPANY, CTO_NAME).

I would like to have something like that:

```
CTO_RECNUM  CTO_COMPANY     CTO_NAME    CTO_TYPE    CTO_INFO
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
12435       HIS COMPANY     Mr. SCOTT   'TEL'       'phone_number_here'     1
12436       HIS COMPANY     Mr. SCOTT   'FAX'       'fax_number_here'       1
12437       HIS COMPANY     Mr. SCOTT   'EML'       'email_adresse_here'    1
12438       OTHER COMPANY   Mr. PAUL    'FAX'       'fax_number_here'       2
```

The last column represents the new column.

I added a "CTO_ID" column and I tried to put a trigger on this table:

```
create or replace 
trigger T_TRG_ADD_CTO_ID
before insert or update on T_CONTACT
for each row
declare
    CTO_PREV number;
begin
  select CTO_ID into CTO_PREV from T_CONTACT
  where CTO_COMPANY=:NEW.CTO_COMPANY and CTO_NAME=:NEW.CTO_NAME;

    if(CTO_PREV is not null) then
     :NEW.CTO_ID:=CTO_PREV;
    else
     :NEW.CTO_ID:=T_SEQ_CTO_ID.NEXTVAL;
    end if;
end;
```

Before inserting or updating a row I try to find in the table if a CTO_ID is already set
for the couple (CTO_COMPANY, CTO_NAME) for the current row (the row that will be inserted or updated).

If a value is found then I put it in the :NEW.CTO_ID. If not, I take a value from a sequence that I have created.

I thought that will be enough to resolve my problem but this trigger returns an exception: `Mutating table`. After researches I found that I am not allowed to select data from a table that is in use in the same trigger.

Please, can you help me to find a solution to my problem ?

Comment: Do you really want a new column, or do you just want to guarantee uniqueness on (CTO_COMPANY, CTO_NAME)?

Comment: I really need this new column. I will have to do some stuff with the values I'll get.

Comment: Does the actual value have to be permanent, or could it be applied when the data is queried? Or in a view, or materialised view? Will the actual number matter - does it just have to be the same for each query, or only matters within a query? Can you add another table that has the unique company/name values with an ID field you can use as an FK? (Making the company/name in this table duplicates and breaking normalisation, but still...)

Comment: Yes, the value has to be permanent and the number matter because I will use these values for an other project. I can add an other table but my company ask me to not duplicate data if it's possible...

Comment: Can you split the single table into two tables: `cto_main(id, rec_num, company_name)` and  `cto_contacts(id, contact_name, cto_main_id, cto_type, cto_info)`?

Comment: Unfortunately it is not possible.

Comment: I don't think you can avoid duplication then, unfortunately. Unless you can do that split and then have a view that joins the two tables, with the same name as the original table - which should be transparent to queries, at least. Otherwise I think you're stuck with duplicating the two fields in a look-up table.